# Placing an object at a known point on a sphere ThreeJS

Tags: math, three.js, trigonometry

I have a sphere geometry at 0, 0, 0 in a scene in Three.js

At known points on the edge of this sphere, I need to place smaller spheres.

I know the theta and phi positions I need to place these objects, but I cannot calculate the x, y and z positions of the smaller spheres.

I can place it at any point on the theta by setting the vector to sit at the phi start of the larger sphere and rotating it, but I can't control where it sits on the theta.

Here are the two techniques I've tried so far, maybe I'm close but I could be miles off.

```
const pos = new THREE.Vector3(-SHOP_TARGET_DISTANCE, 0, 0);
pos.applyAxisAngle(new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0), Math.PI / 2);
pos.applyAxisAngle(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1), Math.PI / 2);
```

and

```
const phi = Math.PI * 1;
const theta = 0;
const x = (SHOP_TARGET_DISTANCE * Math.sin(phi) * Math.cos(theta));
const y = (SHOP_TARGET_DISTANCE * Math.sin(phi) * Math.sin(theta));
const z = SHOP_TARGET_DISTANCE * Math.cos(phi);
const pos = new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z);
```

Comment: use spherical coords https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system to get your x, y, z position

Comment: use `var spherical = new THREE.Spherical();` // create once. Then `spherical.set( radius, phi, theta ); object.position.setFromSpherical( spherical );`